# How do I check if an IPFS-Hash is valid or not, as an input?

Tags: solidity, javascript

I wanna store *Ipfs-hashes* (*Content Identifier*) on the blockchain in the code below.

And because it's public and anybody can use it, I want to make sure the function only accepts valid *Cids* (i.e., the user shouldn't be able to input any random string), and reverts if it's an invalid one.
And since IPFS uses *multihash* (Multiformats CIDs) which can upgrade with time, and I won't be able to make changes to the contract once deployed, I need a validation method that can work with the so called multiformat-Cids.

```
//Solidity function for storing cids    
function addCid(string _cid) public {
    require(_cid == valid, "Invalid Cid"); //I need help with the condition here
    proceedAndSaveCid(_cid);
    }
```

There's a *js-library* that does the same and can be used on the frontend side, *[is-ipfs](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/is-ipfs)*.